# Как провалидировать дто на пустой объект?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dto

В `asp net core` есть атрибуты для вадилации полей дто-объектов, можно ли как-то навесить автрибут валидации на весь класс? В дто-объекте много полей и не хочется в контроллере вручную проверять на наличие каждое поле.

Comment: ASP - старая технология, несвязанная с asp.net core, поэтому я удалил метку. / Добавьте метку используемого языка программирования (скорее всего, C#) - это привлечёт больше внимания к вопросу.

Comment: Создайте в этом классе свойство `public bool IsValid => GetIsValid();` и в этом методе проверяйте все нужные значения, а в контроллере используйте это свойство для проверки.